# java problems buliding a list with specefic structure

Tags: java, list

I am farily new to Java and I have a small problem. I have a function that returns a `String` and a function that returns an `int` and I must put them into a list looking like this `({String, int},{String, int})`. How would I best do that?

Comment: you should make bean class for this or use Collection API .use HashMap]

Comment: Either a `Map<String,Integer>` or `List<CustomObject>`.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem, but there are no tuples in Java like there are in Python.  Encapsulate the two values in an object of some kind and add them to a List.

Comment: thanks for the fast asnwers and i think that i would like to use `List<CustomObject>` but how would i be able to get that specefic structure of the list?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is what @duffymo is describing on his comment, then I don't think Java does that. But you can turn the issue all round by creating a class that has two fields.

```
private String methodForString() {
    String result = new String();
    // ... your code which manipulates result
    return result;
}

private int methodForInt() {
    int result = 0;
    // ... your code which manipulates result
    return result;
}

class MyClass {
    String returnString;
    int returnInt;

    public String getReturnString() {
        return returnString;
    }

    public void setReturnString(String returnString) {
        this.returnString = returnString;
    }

    public int getReturnInt() {
        return returnInt;
    }

    public void setReturnInt(int returnInt) {
        this.returnInt = returnInt;
    }
}

private void initializingMethod() {
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int numberItems = 100;// this represents the number of items you want to
                            // put in your list
    for (int i = 0; i < numberItems; i++) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setReturnInt(methodForInt());
        myClass.setReturnString(methodForString());
        list.add(myClass);
    }
}
```